# Using field without map to the database

Tags: xml, odoo-9, odoo-view

I need to define a field that is not mapped to the database. What I did was:

```
var1 = fields.Char()
var2 = fields.Char()
var3 = fields.Float(manual=True)
```

As expected, it was only the mapped field var1 and var2. But my problem is the use of the var3 in my view. I need it only for temporary use, to store a value to address the submission form.

```
<tree editable="bottom" create="false">
    <field name="var1" readonly="1"/>
    <field name="var2" readonly="1"/>
    <field name="var3"/>
</tree>
```

I want the user to set the variable with a value, and submission treat this value and remove the variable var3 not to store in the database.

But the problem is that, ODOO try something like `select var1, var2, var3 from table`, and var3 is not mapped in the database.

What I need is a tree, similar to the following:

```
var1       var2       var3
regA   descriptionA    10
regB   descriptionB    57
```

Anyone has a solution for my problem, or a best approach to this?

Comment: please make your var3 field as with compute attribute and store=False in that field

Comment: Hi @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa thanks but not works...

Comment: add your code in your question over hear what you have tried